# Spark dataframe databricks csv appends extra double quotes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

It seems that when I apply `CONCAT` on a `dataframe` in `spark sql` and store that `dataframe` as csv file in a `HDFS` location, then  there are extra double quotes added to that `concat` column alone in the ouput file .

This double quotes are not added when I appy show.This double quotes are added only when I store that `dataframe` as a csv file

It seems that I need to remove the  extra double quotes that gets added when I save the `dataframe` as csv file.

I am using the `com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.1.0` jar

Spark Version is 1.5.0-cdh5.5.1

**Input :**

```
 campaign_file_name_1, campaign_name_1, shagdhsjagdhjsagdhrSqpaKa5saoaus89,    1
 campaign_file_name_1, campaign_name_1, sagdhsagdhasjkjkasihdklas872hjsdjk,    2
```

Expected output :

```
 campaign_file_name_1, shagdhsjagdhjsagdhrSqpaKa5saoaus89,     campaign_name_1"="1,  2017-06-06 17:09:31
 campaign_file_name_1, sagdhsagdhasjkjkasihdklas872hjsdjk,   campaign_name_1"="2,  2017-06-06 17:09:31
```

**Spark Code :**

```
  object campaignResultsMergerETL extends BaseETL {

  val now  = ApplicationUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp()
  val conf = new Configuration()
  val fs  = FileSystem.get(conf)
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //---------------------
    code for sqlContext Initialization 
    //---------------------
    val campaignResultsDF  = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(campaignResultsLoc)
    campaignResultsDF.registerTempTable("campaign_results")
    val campaignGroupedDF =  sqlContext.sql(
   """
    |SELECT campaign_file_name,
    |campaign_name,
    |tracker_id,
    |SUM(campaign_measure) AS campaign_measure
    |FROM campaign_results
    |GROUP BY campaign_file_name,campaign_name,tracker_id
  """.stripMargin)

    campaignGroupedDF.registerTempTable("campaign_results_full")

    val campaignMergedDF =  sqlContext.sql(
  s"""
    |SELECT campaign_file_name,
    |tracker_id,
    |CONCAT(campaign_name,'\"=\"' ,campaign_measure),
    |"$now" AS audit_timestamp
    |FROM campaign_results_full
  """.stripMargin)

   campaignMergedDF.show(20)
   saveAsCSVFiles(campaignMergedDF, campaignResultsExportLoc, numPartitions)

   }


    def saveAsCSVFiles(campaignMeasureDF:DataFrame,hdfs_output_loc:String,numPartitions:Int): Unit =
    {
       log.info("saveAsCSVFile method started")
       if (fs.exists(new Path(hdfs_output_loc))){
          fs.delete(new Path(hdfs_output_loc), true)
       }
     campaignMeasureDF.repartition(numPartitions).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(hdfs_output_loc)
       log.info("saveAsCSVFile method ended")
    }

 }
```

Result of `campaignMergedDF.show(20)` is correct and works fine.

```
 campaign_file_name_1, shagdhsjagdhjsagdhrSqpaKa5saoaus89,   campaign_name_1"="1,  2017-06-06 17:09:31
 campaign_file_name_1, sagdhsagdhasjkjkasihdklas872hjsdjk,   campaign_name_1"="2,  2017-06-06 17:09:31
```

Result of `saveAsCSVFiles` : This is incorrect .

```
 campaign_file_name_1, shagdhsjagdhjsagdhrSqpaKa5saoaus89,   "campaign_name_1""=""1",  2017-06-06 17:09:31
 campaign_file_name_1, sagdhsagdhasjkjkasihdklas872hjsdjk,   "campaign_name_1""=""2",  2017-06-06 17:09:31
```

Could some one help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using

```
write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(hdfs_output_loc)
```

In order to write a text which includes `"` into a csv file, you are facing problems as the `"` sign is defined as default quote by *spark-csv*

Replacing the default quote from `"` to something else (e.g. NULL) should allow you to write `"` to the file as is.

```
write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quote", "\u0000").save(hdfs_output_loc)
```

**Explanation:**

You are using the default spark-csv:

- *escape* value which is `\`
- *quote* value which is `"`

[spark-csv doc](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

- quote: by default the quote character is ", but can be set to any character. Delimiters inside quotes are ignored
- escape: by default the escape character is \, but can be set to any character. Escaped quote characters are ignored

[This answer](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8515/datawriteformatcomdatabrickssparkcsv-added-additio.html) suggested the following:

> The way to turn off the default escaping of the double quote character
>   (") with the backslash character () - i.e. to avoid escaping for all
>   characters entirely, you must add an .option() method call with just
>   the right parameters after the .write() method call. The goal of the
>   option() method call is to change how the csv() method "finds"
>   instances of the "quote" character as it is emitting the content. To
>   do this, you must change the default of what a "quote" actually means;
>   i.e. change the character sought from being a double quote character
>   (") to a Unicode "\u0000" character (essentially providing the Unicode
>   NUL character assuming it won't ever occur within the document).

Comment: @SurenderRaja - Great! :-)